# Image from extension appears as broken link when referenced from content-script

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a small content-script for a Chrome extension which inserts an image in a webpage, but when I watch a processed webpage the image appears as if the link was broken.

The image is at the root of my Chrome extension. I am using the getURL function from the extension API:

```
$('<div class="my-image"><img src=' +
    chrome.extension.getURL("icon16.png") +
    ' />This is my image</div>');
```

When I inspect the webpage, I see that the URL is:

```
<img src="chrome-extension://cemgjkpboohlaaccmholgleljodgecod/icon16.png">
```

I can't figure out what I did wrong. Please help me, I am stuck and clueless.

EDIT: Note: the link is indeed correct because when I click on "Open Image in New Tab", the icon is displayed correctly.

Comment: What's your Chrome version? When you watch the Network tab, does anything show up? Does any error show up in the console?

Comment: Chrome version 18.0.1025.142 on MacOSX 10.7.3.

Comment: Thanks to you, I noticed a suspect error in the Network tab:

initiator is: chrome-extension://eccjgancceeifipagkhggplcohgcgloa/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

"url": "chrome-extension://invalid/",   <---- that's probably the source of the problem, but I don't know how to interpret this error.

Comment: Note: I am a total beginner with Javascript, I might have made a basic mistake in the way to use jquery. I just placed the latest version I found on the jquery's website in the root dir of the extension, and added it to the content-script list in the manifest: 

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "content_script.js"]
    }
  ],

Comment: You dont happen to have `"manifest_version" : 2` in your manifest do you?

Comment: I had "manifest_version" : 2 in my manifest and if I remove it it fixes the problem ! ^_^

Please write your solution in the proper form (an answer) so I can mark it as solution to make it searchable for others. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of answer is that? "use old manifest and you are good to go", of course use newest! 
Old is old. It's depreciated.

Read documentation:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#extension-files

you can use extension's files with manifest 2.

```
//Code for displaying <extensionDir>/images/myimage.png:
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("images/myimage.png");
document.getElementById("someImage").src = imgURL;
```

also you have to add your images to web_accessible_resources, that you are going to use outside extension, e.g. content script inserts it into some user's website:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

manifest.json:

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png",
    "style/double-rainbow.css",
    "script/double-rainbow.js",
    "script/main.js",
    "templates/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You CAN downgrade your manifest version to a deprecated version (using 1 instead of 2), but the way you're supposed to do it in the v2 world is by whitelisting the assets you intend to embed in the page using the `web_accessible_resources`, described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html).

This is because of a change in the default availability of assets in manifest v2:

> #### Default Availablility
>
> Resources inside of packages using manifest_version 2 or above are blocked by default, and must be whitelisted for use via this property.

Comment: It's worst solution you can use.

Comment: I don't really follow -- I describe the same solution that you do and explain why it's necessary.