# Chrome extension - image can't found to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome-extension

While developing a Chrome extension, I am injecting an image from image folder via content javascript. But chrome is not able to inject/load it in to webpages and showing a broken image instead of image.

By inspecting webpages I have found src=chrome-extension://mjpjhbhenfpklnbkbegbhdnganbppjdd/images/imgage1.png , clicking on it will be opened image in new tab.

For problem understanding, I have pasted here related code of menifest.json file and contentscript.js

In menifest.json file (version 2),

```
 "web_accessible_resouces" : ["jquery.js","contentscript.js","images/image1.png"],
```

In contentscript.js

```
var imurl = chrome.extension.getURL('/images/image1.png');

$jq(this).html( $jq(this).html().replace(/(\d-\d)/g,"<a href='#' class='anchr'>$1</a><img width='10' length='10' src='"+imurl+"' class='image1' >") );
```

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is security limitation for resource injection. Pass image using content scripts as [data-uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

You content script could look like

```
var imdata = data-uri-here;
$jq(this).html( $jq(this).html().replace(/(\d-\d)/g,"<a href='#' class='anchr'>$1</a><img width='10' length='10' src='"+imdata+"' class='image1' >") )
```

Comment: Thanks Andreyl, I am newbi for this. Can you please provide me a reproducible code to perform this. Alsop let me know when this code should be included whether in content or background script?

Comment: I've updated my answer with sample code based on your original code. Please check wiki article how to make data-uri string from your image

Comment: There is a better solution for this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23052827/212107